# Increasing the scope of object from local scope

Tags: java

I want to create an object using a method but I want it (object+reference) to live even after the method ends. Example of code:

```
public class start{
public static void main (String [] Args){
  public void createObject(){
    object1 createdObject = new object1();
  }
  createObject();
  createdObject.doSomething();
 }
}

public class object1{
   //code for object 1
}
```

So my main question is: how to create object using method and let it live even after method ends. The problem is that reference `createdObject` is popped of `stack` after method ends and therefore I can't use it anymore. Is it even possible to create object for further use this way?

Comment: does not make sense? What exactly is the question? And what are u trying to do here `ui createdObject = new ui();`

Comment: Does this code actually compile?

Comment: `public class start` does it compile?

Comment: no this code doesnt compile it was just example to let you know what I am trying to do. Forgot about ui createdObject = new ui(); lets just say that I want to create object using method and I want it to live (reference+object) even after method ends. I am just asking if this is possible.

Comment: I have edited the question to make more sense and describe what am I trying to do

Comment: increase the scope to class level and it will live

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class start{
public static void main (String [] Args){

//class level scope
object1 createdObject = null;

 private void createObject(){
    createdObject = new object1();
  }
}

public class object1{
   //code for object 1
}
```

**NOTE: I have not following naming conventions. But please follow them in actual code**

**UPDATE:** Proper code check it out

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         new MyClass().doSomething();
    }

}


class MyClass{
    Object obj ;

    public void doSomething(){
        createObject();
    }


    private void createObject(){
        obj = new Object();
        System.out.println("Created MyClass instance");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting error on line private void createObject(){. Here is what compiler says: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s),
Syntax error on token "void", @ expected. Anyway nice solution, never thought of it this way. But I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your method should return object1 instead of void and you have to add the following line at the end of the method:

```
return createdObject;
```